# Last ion-radio is always selected

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, radio-button, ionic3

I have a list of people and for each, I need to check if they are alive, dead or are zombis (all radios in the same line). The problem is that if I use the code below, zombi is always selected with no chance to change it. How can I make it work as needed?

```
    <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="person1">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Alice</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="alive"></ion-radio>
        <ion-radio value="dead"></ion-radio>
        <ion-radio value="zombi"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to place all the radio items in the same row, you can use `ion-row` and `ion-col` elements like this:

```
 <ion-row radio-group [(ngModel)]="person1">
    <ion-col>
      <ion-item>
        Alice
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Alive</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="alive"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-item>
       <ion-label>Dead</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="dead"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-item>
       <ion-label>Zombie</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="zombie"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```